# Como desativar formatação de classes names em html do prettier?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, tailwind

É possível ignorar a formatação dos nomes das classes sem desativar o prettier? Essa formatação atrapalha na legibilidade do html usando tailwind

Em vez disso:

```
<button
  class="
    bg-gray-500
    hover:bg-gray-700
    font-bold
    uppercase
    px-2
    py-4
    rounded
  "
>
    Login
</button>
```

Ficar desse jeito:

```
<button class="bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-700 font-bold uppercase px-2 py-4 rounded">
  Login
</button>
```